# Pip installed package not visible in conda environment

Tags: python, pip, conda, virtual-environment

I am working in a conda environment (called python36)

I have installed a package 'bctpy' while in this environment via

```
pip install bctpy
```

When I now try to import this module (while still in this environment)

```
import bctpy
```

I receive the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bctpy'
```

When I run:

```
conda list
```

from the command prompt the module is there, but when in python I run

```
help()
modules
```

The outputs of which pip and which python are below:

```
(python36) bash-4.1$ which pip
/home/.conda/envs/python36/bin/pip
(python36) bash-4.1$ which python
/home/.conda/envs/python36/bin/python
```

It is not visible. is anyone able to explain what is going wrong?

Comment: Can you give the output of `which pip` and `which python`?

Comment: thanks, have edited the question to include

Comment: As `tests/basic_tests.py` shows, the import is `import bct`, not `import bctpy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem that one can encounter every now and then:

The PIP package is derived from the [PyPI name `bctpy`](https://pypi.org/project/bctpy/)

```
pip install bctpy
```

but the import name is derived from the [top level directory name: `bct/`](https://github.com/aestrivex/bctpy), so it must be imported like

```
import bct
```

Comment: Many thanks Nils, could you let me know how you worked that out?

Comment: @RobMcC Perhaps differently, but if you see my comment, you see how I worked it out: tests can work great as simple examples of a package's usage.

Answer (score -1):

Since i could not get it after my pip install ImageHash i tried following
1. Update index in Anaconda 
2. Update channel

None of them helped.

but when i went to Anaconda -> Environments tab -> Click on triangle mark next to base(root) -> Open terminal -> ran command conda install -c conda-forge imagehash

Immediately after this i was able to see the package.